# single quote and year formatting in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I remove a single quote and `yy` from combined name in excel?
For example, I want:
`Francis B. and Edith Campbell` from `Francis B. '42 and Edith Campbell`
 and
`Pimmett E. Dusharm` from `Pimmett E. Dusharm '42`

Comment: I think you have some typos there. How do you get `Emmett E. Dusharm` from `Pimmett E. Duszarm '42`? Or `Francis B. and Edith Campbell` from `Franzis B. '42 and Epith Campbell`?  What if you have `Franzis B. '42 and Epith Campbell '42`?

Comment: did either of these answers help you?  If so, you should accept one of the answers so other users know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

If the year is always last in every string you can remove the last 4 characters:

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-4)
```

Another option could be to simply do a find and replace to remove all numbers and the single quote.

Comment: See the example `Franzis B. '42 and Epith Campbell`; '42 is not at the end of the string

Comment: Also, what happens if you have someone named `Miles O'Brien`?

Comment: That's why you search for " '" (space quote) rather than just the single quote